# sunspot reindex error (progress_bar related)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I encounter error when trying to reindex sunspot. I already tried stop/delete solr folder, install and start again but problem is still there.

```
☁ [master] ⚡ bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex --trace        
** Invoke sunspot:reindex (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:reindex
Error using progress bar: undefined method `at' for ProgressBar::Time:Class
```

I alraedy try replacing schema.xml as it fix other developer with the same issue but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you solved above issue? I am also facing same issue. Can you please update it if you find any solution.

Comment: hi @Swati , No. I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This [pull request](https://github.com/paul/progress_bar/pull/22) to progress_bar fixed the progress bar error. Upgrade your version of progress_bar to a version including this patch (version 1.0.1 and above).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by commenting out the `rails_best_practices` gem in Gemfile.